# Deriving the city and state from the location Facebook permission in Laravel 4

Tags: arrays, facebook, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to separate out the city and state from the location array object from Facebook in Laravel.  Before when I did this, I simply tried something similar to what I am trying in my Oauth2 Controller:

```
$citystate = $user['location'];
$citystate2 = $citystate['name'];
$split = explode(", ", $citystate2);
$city = $split[0];
$state = $split[1];
```

In the provider file, Facebook.php, I have this:

```
'location' => $user->location
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

```
Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'
```

So, my question is, how do I access the "name" portion of the location array object.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should `json_decode` (if it's a json string) like

```
$userArray  = json_decode($user, true);
```

So, you can use it like an array

```
$citystate = $userArray['location'];
```

Also you can check if the `$user` is already an array or not using

```
if(is_array($user) && array_key_exists('location', $user)) {
    // ...
    $citystate = $user['location'];
    // ...
}
```

Then you'll get an array like this

```
array (size=2)
 'id' => string 'xxx' (length=15) // xxx = digits
 'name' => string 'Sylhet' (length=6)
```

**Update :** `$user['location']` is an object :

```
object(stdClass)#180 (2) { ["id"]=> string(15) "114952118516947" ["name"]=> string(25) "San Francisco, California" }
```

So, it should be :

```
$citystate = $user['location'];
$citystate->name;
```

Comment: I get this error when I do this:

json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Then it's already an array, no need to `json_decode`, try `var_dump($user)` and see what you get ?

Comment: This is the output for the location object ($user['location']):

object(stdClass)#180 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(15) "114952118516947"
  ["name"]=>
  string(25) "San Francisco, California"
}

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I just had to use the location->name arrow attribute.